# Is there any windows API to execute thread on atomic mode?

Tags: c++, c, driver

Is there any windows API (application program interface) to execute thread on atomic mode?

Comment: What's "atomic mode"?

Comment: execute operation without context switch

Comment: Obviously Not. That's what *preemptive* multitasking (in contrast to cooperative multitasking) means. Preemption means the operating system may preempt your thread at any moment (for any reason or for no reason at all as far as you're concerned), and it actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Interlocked API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx) may be what you are looking for. Or more generally, [here is the MSDN topic on synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681924(v=vs.85).aspx).